# Can't seem to make my css grid to stretch on a full page width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I tried to set `margin` and `padding` to `0`, which works on the left side of the **grid** but I still a huge white space on the right side.
If I don't specify `margin`/`padding`, I just have equal white spaces on both sides. Also, my `.nav-bar` is in full width so it seems that the problem is just with the grid.

I also tried to play with that using the developer tools on Chrome and nothing.
I tried a lot of solutions posted, but nothing worked.

Here's my HTML (short):

```
<body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-side-bar">
        </div>
        <div class="main1">
        </div>
        <div class="main2">
        </div>
        <div class="right-side-bar">
        </div>  
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*NAV*/
.nav-bar {
    background-color: black;
}

.main-nav {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.push {
    margin-left: auto; 
}

.main-nav li {
    padding: 20px;
}

.main-nav a {
    color: #f5f5f6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code works perfectly fine. Need some more code or demo page.

Looks like you are although using **Bootstrap** CSS library. Class `.container` is one of basic BS classes, which provides `max-width: 1140px;` and `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`. So yes, when you set `margin: 0;` - the `.container` goes left, but still not full width. Try to change the class name to any other.

Is you not using Bootstrap - try to set to `.container`'s CSS `width: 100% !important; margin: 0;` and if it doesn't help - insect this element and every parent element for any `width`, `display` and `position` settings, in console.

Comment: Yes, I actually figured it out by myself and got rid of Bootstrap in my code. Thank you!